# To what extent should a database be normalized?

Tags: database, database-normalization

Personally I find database *normalization* really interesting(in fact really enjoy doing it) but while designing the schema and normalizing it for the asset manager(containing generic and project specific assets with each having types of arbitrary relation depth) I am currently working on, I came to this basic question i.e. to what extent should one *normalize* a database(I am aware of *3NF*) such that making multiple query, insert etc, doesn't become more costly than programmatically taking care of data *inconsistencies*, *redundancy* etc which *normalization* tries to avoid?

Comment: I would say it depends how you want to optimize it. Do you want to design for fast queries like reporting? Or for quick storage? Perpaps two databases, normalized and denormalized for both purposes?

Comment: I would say it largely depends.3NF will allow you to perform many future modifications / queries without much extra though. As soon as your DB is not well normalized, it will be a headache for any future developers that do not know which areas are/aren't normalized

Comment: this would probably be better on the dba stack exchange

Comment: Use good sense. For example, a table of street names with keyed access from the address table is silly in most cases. Maybe a table of addresses tied to a table of people is reasonable. Maybe just put a few more columns in the people table. You can go too far or you can denormalize too much.

Comment: @Aphelion well, currently, my concern is more inclined towards fast queries. But in fact for the application even if I normalize it completely I won't be facing as such any performance issues. Just that I was being curious to know and therefore a multifaceted answer would be much appreciated.

Comment: Any time you denormalize you create a potentional maintenance issue. One thing is to keep this in mind while developing the application, another is instructing other (future) developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In designing your database you should normalize it to the fullest extend (well, with common sence in mind). While developing you'll notice some potential performance issues. In this case you may want to resort to using views or even *denormalize* a bit.

Though this differs from case to case, since some programs have serious requirements on performance. Others may be used by just a few users, in this case performance may not be that important.

In order to make a good decision on whether or not to denormalize and thus being able to execute simpler queries, you should run some performance tests for both cases. Keeping in mind what denormalizing would cause to the maintenance of your database.

In case of denormalizing, be sure to document this to the fullest extend.